How to replicate Phong shading with a high specular highlight in WebGL using Three.js?
I'm trying to render two spheres in Three.js with custom Phong shading using GLSL shaders. I want the right sphere to have a high specular highlight, similar to the one in this reference image, where it appears glossy with a sharp specular reflection. However, my left sphere currently looks too diffuse and lacks the desired highlight intensity.
By Focus on finalizing the vertex and fragment shaders only—no changes elsewhere. and by Keeping the parameter values for the fragment shader as they are.
ref image:

here is my current code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>phong shading</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { display: block; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

            uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix; // optional when using ShaderMaterial
            uniform mat4 projectionMatrix; // optional when using ShaderMaterial
            uniform mat4 viewMatrix; // optional when using ShaderMaterial
            uniform mat4 modelMatrix; // optional when using ShaderMaterial
            uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
            uniform mat4 inverseTransposeM;

            uniform vec3 eyePos;
            attribute vec3 position;
            attribute vec3 normal;
            varying vec3 v_normal, v_view;

            void main() {
                v_normal = normal;
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            }

        </script>

        <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

            precision mediump float;
            precision mediump int;

            vec3 matDiff, matSpec, matAmbi, matEmit;
            float matSh;
            vec3 srcDiff, srcSpec, srcAmbi;

            uniform vec3 lightDir;
            varying vec3 v_normal, v_view;

            void main() {
                
                // Material properties
                matDiff = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // Diffuse color (green)
                matSpec = vec3(2.0, 2.0, 2.0); // Increase specular intensity
                matAmbi = vec3(0.0, 0.15, 0.0); // Slightly increased ambient intensity
                matSh = 500.0;                  // High shininess for a tight highlight
                
                // Light properties
                srcDiff = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Diffuse light color
                srcSpec = vec3(2.0, 2.0, 2.0); // Specular light color
                srcAmbi = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Ambient light color
        
                // Normalize the normal and light direction
                vec3 N = normalize(v_normal);
                vec3 L = normalize(lightDir);
                vec3 V = normalize(v_view); // View direction (towards the camera)
                vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);    // Reflection direction
        
                // Ambient component
                vec3 ambient = matAmbi * srcAmbi;
        
                // Diffuse component
                float diffFactor = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);
                vec3 diffuse = matDiff * srcDiff * diffFactor;
        
                // Specular component
                float specFactor = pow(max(dot(R, V), 0.0), matSh);
                vec3 specular = matSpec * srcSpec * specFactor;
        
                // Combine components
                vec3 color = ambient + diffuse + specular;
        
                // Set fragment color
                gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
            }

        </script>
        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.157.0/build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.157.0/examples/jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script type="module">
            import * as THREE from 'three';
            import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 500 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 3, -10 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
        
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

            const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

            const ambilight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.1);
            scene.add(ambilight);
            const dlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
            dlight.position.set(5, 2, -5);
            dlight.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            scene.add(dlight);
            scene.add(dlight.target);

            const geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 30, 20 );
            const mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                color: 0xFF0000,
                flatShading: false,
            });

            const ball = new THREE.Mesh(geom,mat);
            scene.add(ball);
            ball.position.set(1.5,0,0);

            let m = new THREE.Matrix4();

            let uniforms = {
                inverseTransposeM:{type:"mat4", value:m},
                eyePos:{type:"vec3", value:camera.position},
                lightDir:{type:"vec3", value:dlight.position}
            }
            const mat2 = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
                uniforms: uniforms,
                vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
                fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
            });

            const ball2 = new THREE.Mesh(geom,mat2)
            scene.add(ball2);
            ball2.position.set(-1.5,0,0);
            ball2.material.uniforms.inverseTransposeM.value = ball2.matrixWorld.invert().transpose();

            function animate(time) {
                controls.update();
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

and here is my current result:

What I've tried:
Increasing matSh and matSpec values
Adjusting srcSpec and srcAmbi values
Desired Outcome:
I want the green sphere to appear with a high specular highlight, giving it a glossy, reflective look.
